# Finding all functions of certain type

Tags: go

Is there a way to list out all functions that uses/returns a specific type?

For example: I'm interested to use the following function.

```
  func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error
```

How can I find out all functions (across all Go packages) that can return a Handler?

Comment: thanks, i looked at that but not really aligned with what I'm looking, but yeah if it works for handler interface, probably provide hints to my question too.

Comment: gopls and go guru (ex oracle).

Comment: Thanks @Volker. I looked at Guru before and the nearest I can figure out that should answer the question is having Type query as "Implement". However, Guru goes through the source code and not all modules.

For example, `func CheckTime( t time.time )`

i was trying to figure out what are all the modules/pkg that returns a `time.time`

Answer (score 0):

I'd write an analysis tool using the `x/tools/go/analysis` framework. Here's a rough sketch that you can run on any module (it uses `go/packages` underneath so it fully supports modules):

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/format"
    "go/token"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/singlechecker"
)

var RtAnalysis = &analysis.Analyzer{
    Name: "rtanalysis",
    Doc:  "finds functions by return type",
    Run:  run,
}

func main() {
    singlechecker.Main(RtAnalysis)
}

func run(pass *analysis.Pass) (interface{}, error) {
    for _, file := range pass.Files {
        ast.Inspect(file, func(n ast.Node) bool {
            if funcTy, ok := n.(*ast.FuncType); ok {
                if funcTy.Results != nil {
                    for _, fl := range funcTy.Results.List {
                        if tv, ok := pass.TypesInfo.Types[fl.Type]; ok {
                            if tv.Type.String() == "net/http.Handler" {
                                ns := nodeString(funcTy, pass.Fset)
                                fmt.Printf("%s has return of type net/http.Handler\n", ns)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true
        })
    }

    return nil, nil
}

// nodeString formats a syntax tree in the style of gofmt.
func nodeString(n ast.Node, fset *token.FileSet) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    format.Node(&buf, fset, n)
    return buf.String()
}
```